# Populate modal form with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, getjson

I have a modal form that I created like this:

```
    function addeditNote(rowID,callback) {
        var ret;
        jQuery.fancybox({
            modal : true,
            overlayOpacity : 0.25,
            content : "<div class=\"contentbox modal-window modal-400\"><div class=\"boxbody\"><div class=\"boxheader clear\"><h2>Add / Edit User Notes</h2></div><br /><div class=\"box-wrap clear\"><form action=\"\" method=\"post\" class=\"form bt-space0\"><div class=\"columns clear bt-space0\"><div class=\"colText fl\"><div class=\"form-field clear\"><label for=\"textfield\" class=\"formlabel size-20 fl-space2\">Name: </label><input type=\"text\" id=\"name\" class=\"text fl-space2\" /></div><div class=\"form-field clear\"><div class=\"fl-space2\"><label for=\"textarea\" class=\"formlabel size-20\">Notes: </label></div><textarea id=\"note\" class=\"form-textarea display\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"6\" name=\"form[note]\" rel=\"textarea\"></textarea></div></div></div><div class=\"columns clear bt-space5\"></div><div class=\"form-field clear\"><input id=\"addeditNote_cancel\" class=\"button fr-space2\" type=\"button\" value=\"Cancel\"><input id=\"addeditNote_ok\" class=\"button green fr-space\" type=\"button\" value=\"Enter\"></div></form></div><!-- end of box-wrap --></div> <!-- end of box-body --></div>",
    
    
    
            onComplete : function() {
                jQuery("#addeditNote_cancel").click(function() {
                    ret = false;
                    jQuery.fancybox.close();
                })
                jQuery("#addeditNote_ok").click(function() {
                    ret = true;
                    jQuery.fancybox.close();
                })
            },
            onClosed : function() {
                callback.call(this,ret);
            }
        });
}
```

I get my json string like:

```
$.getJSON("GetNotes.php?id=" + rowID,
    function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            $('#' + item.field).val(item.value);
                 });
});
```

Which returns:

> {"op": "UPDATE", "id": "7","name": "Joe Public","note": "Dennis likes his coffee in the morning... He doesn't drink tea and coffee always have powdered creamer and 2 sugar's." }

The "op" just a placeholder so I know if a note exists then I'm updating the database and if it doesn't then I'm inserting..

My problem is, I do not know where to put this to populate the form..  I'm still learning so was hoping someone could give me a clue how this works..  :)

Comment: do your form element names match up with your json object properties ?

Comment: Yes..   I am not sure if I can call if from within the function I have that generates the window though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't work to populate the form in the same function that creates the window, try adding it as a call in the onComplete handler:

```
onComplete : function() {
    //All of your original code here
    $.getJSON( /* with your JSON code here */ );
},
```

Presumably the dialog should be ready by that time, and you can load things into the form elements as normal.

Comment: Ahh.. I though the onComplete was when I fired an event such as closing or a button click?  I'll give that a try..

Comment: According to http://fancybox.net/api, onComplete "Will be called once the content is displayed." Hope that works for you!